# Entity framework open connections

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

We have a site running on ASP.NET 4.5 using a (shared) SQL Server database. Our ISP has recently told us that we have too many open connections and it is affecting the overall stability of the server. At high loads this number can reach as many as 400+ open connections with around 200 concurrent users visiting the site.

The site is made up mostly of content such as reviews and blog posts and we have implemented caching throughout the site. We are using Entity Framework exclusively to query the database. We use StructureMap to inject our connection string into our business logic classes.

StructureMap initialization:

```
var ecsbuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
ecsbuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
ecsbuilder.ProviderConnectionString = @"data source=***;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;User ID=***;Password=***;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework";
ecsbuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Data.***.csdl|res://*/Data.***.ssdl|res://*/Data.***.msl";
string connectionString = ecsbuilder.ToString();
For<SiteModelContainer>().Use<SiteModelContainer>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(connectionString);
For<IGalleryService>().Use<GalleryService>();
...all the rest of our services
```

Then in our services (e.g. `GalleryService`) we have the following:

```
private readonly SiteModelContainer _context;

public GalleryService(SiteModelContainer context)
{
    this._context = context;
}
```

In our service methods we just use `_context` to query the database

My questions are:

1. If this is the only way we are querying the database is it not closing the connections for some reason?
2. What methods can I use to determine where the connections are being left open?

Thanks

Comment: This also happened to me even though i used "using" statement but was unable to find from where connections were leaking.

Comment: connection pooling should help some. also may want to consider reworking your caching plan if at all possible. If properly done, caching should be able to remove a significant amount of back-end calls to the db.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I was under the impression that StructureMap disposed of the contexts automatically?

Comment: well i didn't use that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use connection pooling in your connection string.
2. Use using block for the use of context as below.

   //Create a class and static function to get the context

   ```
   public class DaatabaseFramework
   {
       public static SiteModelContainer GetContext()
       {
           return new SiteModelContainer();
       }
   }
   ```

   //Use the below to use the context

   ```
   using (var context=DaatabaseFramework.GetContext())
   {

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was see similar when I try to pass IQueryable variable from using( ... connection ... ) {} block.

When I do this, orphaned connections was stay on my site like yours.

Try to find code like this:

```
public IQueryable<YourClass> func(int param1) {
  using(var context=DaatabaseFramework.GetContext()) {
    return context.MyTable.Where(_=>_.Param1==Param1);
  }
}
```